# Checking if errno != EINTR: what does it mean?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals, posix

I've found this piece of code used several times (also a similar one where it's used `open()` instead of `write()`).

```
int c = write(fd, &v, sizeof(v));
if (c == -1 && errno != EINTR) {
    perror("Write to output file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**Why it is checked if `&& errno != EINTR` here ?**

Looking for `errno` on *man* I found the following text about `EINTR`, but even if I visited `man 7 signal` that doesn't enlighten me.

> EINTR Interrupted function call (POSIX.1); see signal(7).

Comment: Check the man page for `write` instead. It should tell you what errno is set to on certain errors.

Comment: Note also that `write()` returns `ssize_t`, and **NOT** `int`.  They are not the same.

Comment: Thank you both! @AndrewHenle I know it, I just decided to copy the piece of code as I found it :) do you think I should edit the question all the same with `ssize_t` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Many system calls will report the `EINTR` error code if a signal occurred while the system call was in progress. No error actually occurred, it's just reported that way because the system isn't able to resume the system call automatically. This coding pattern simply retries the system call when this happens, to ignore the interrupt.

For instance, this might happen if the program makes use of `alarm()` to run some code asynchronously when a timer runs out. If the timeout occurs while the program is calling `write()`, we just want to retry the system call (aka read/write, etc).

Comment: Might be useful for nerds, [Interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)

Answer (score 11):

the answers here are really good and  i want  to add some internal details :

> System calls that are interrupted by signals can either abort and
>   return `EINTR` or automatically restart themselves
>   if and only  if `SA_RESTART` is specified in `sigaction(2)`

and the one responsible for this task is the `restart_block` which  used to track information and arguments for restarting system calls

Comment: Could you tell me where does the reference come from? I would like to take a look. :)

Comment: @Rick I forget I'm very sorry but I think have to do with x86 and kernel stuff because at that time I was reading a lot of books about how stuff works so maybe Understanding the Linux Kernel book or The Linux Programming Interface book.

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) on `write`:

> The call was interrupted by a signal before any data was written

Comment: This answer is not really sufficient; it doesn't explain the situations under which `EINTR` can (or more importantly, can't) happen. I consider the latter more important because failure to understand that it usually can't happen is a cause of endless cargo-culting.

Comment: @R.. *This answer is not really sufficient; it doesn't explain the situations under which `EINTR` can (or more importantly, can't) happen. I consider the latter more important because failure to understand that it usually can't happen is a cause of endless cargo-culting.* If you don't "cargo cult" system calls, changing something like the signal mask of a process can break things anywhere.  If you like writing fragile code that can be broken by something completely unrelated, that's your choice.  But please don't characterize writing robust code as "cargo-culting".

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Installing an interrupting signal handler is an invasive and intentional thing you do when you *want* to error-out of blocking syscalls that get interrupted. Looping to repeat when that happens does not make sense in general, only when you know you really want that behavior.

Comment: @R.. can you explain (or perhaps just link to an explanation of) a situation that might lead to such a signal handler being a sensible option?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE and this argument works against you, because the last thing I will do when writing a library is implement something like a signal handler. The reality is that I don't know if user will or will not install a signal handler, am I supposed to just go let them write this code by themselves in that case?

Comment: @Sahsahae: In that case you also don't know whether their choice to install an interrupting signal handler represents an **intent** that the code they're calling (your library code) immediately bail out on a signal (the standard semantic for interrupting signals) or an **intent** that your code treat itself as special and try to resume blocking after being interrupted. Since you can't know, doing something special to satisfy an assumption they want the latter seems like a bad idea. Just doing nothing achives the former automatically.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I hope you will one day realize that your argument can be worked all the way backwards till we're left with nothing but a single function that adds two numbers, except we don't know whether user wants the result to be printed or used anywhere so may aswell not write the function because user can just go write everything from scratch, because you're ignoring that libraries exist to solve a specific problem, instead of covering everything ever imaginable.