# Linux C, waitpid() is unblocked by handled signals with return value -1 and errno 5

Tags: c, linux, signals, kill, waitpid

I ran into this problem a few hours ago.

Even though I have fixed it, I simply don't understand why this happens.

```
signal(SIGHUP, sighupHandler);
.
.
.
// sync with child by getting a char written by child
fgetc(pipe_in);
close(pipe_in);
int status;
if(waitpid(initProcessPid, &status, 0) == -1){
    printf("debug: errno is %d\n", errno);
    printf("failed to wait for init process to end\n");
}
```

Every time a SIGHUP happens during the waitpid() block, waitpid() returns -1 with errno 5.

Although a EINTR should be in errno this case as pointed out by alk, EINTR is 4, not 5.

After a few hours gathering ideas from gdb, since I'm not actually doing anything on SIGHUP currently, I changed my code to:

```
signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
```

Then it works properly, SIGHUP no longer breaks the waitpid() block.

I was working on a linux container that aims to be single file and static.
https://github.com/Kethen/minicontainer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41474299/2371524

Comment: From [`waitpid()`'s POSIX docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) (The Linux man page in essence states the same): "***ERRORS**

    The waitpid() function shall fail if: [...]
    [EINTR]
        The function was interrupted by a signal. [...].*"

Comment: Also, don't use `signal()`, as its semantics vary; always use [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead. Also, if you include both `<errno.h>` and `<string.h>`, you can use `strerror(errno)` to get a human-readable error string.

Comment: I see. However my compiled code told me the EINTR is 4, not 5, which confused me earlier...

Comment: Please note that `errno` is a global resource, so either log or save it ***immediately** after* the error condition had been detected. Do not call any function which might modify `errno` before its value had either been logged or saved. Just as the code you show does.

Comment: I see, I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: ... and the code from your git-repo doesn't!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! I'll do that in a bit. Thanks everyone for the responses, too!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [`wait()/waitpid()` POSIX documentaion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html):

> The `wait()` function shall cause the calling thread to become blocked until status information generated by child process termination is made available to the thread, ***or until delivery of a signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process,*** or an error occurs.
>
> If `wait()` or `waitpid()` returns due to the delivery of a signal to the calling process, -1 shall be returned and `errno` set to `[EINTR]`.

Since you've configured `SIGHUP` to execute a function, it's covered by the emphasised clause above.

This is similar to many other system calls which can return `EAGAIN` when interrupted by a signal. One way you can handle it is with code similar to:

```
// Keep waiting while being interrupted.

int rc, err;
do {
    rc = waitpid (initProcessPid, &status, 0);
    err = errno;
} while ((rc == -1) && (err == EINTR));

// Any error other than interruption will be caught here.

if (rc == -1) {
    printf ("debug: errno is %d\n", err);
    printf ("failed to wait for init process to end\n");
}
```

You're also correct that Linux generally states this should be `4` rather than `5` but that's not always the case. Some systems use vastly different values (such as IBM iSeries, putting those common error codes up somewhere about 3400).

You should be checking against the specific *name* rather than a fixed value.