# Understanding sem_timedwait()

Tags: c, semaphore

I am reading the manual on `sem_timedwait()` and cannot figure out the example. I currently understand that:

- If `sem_timedwait()` times out, then it returns -1 and sets `errno` to `ETIMEDOUT`. So I can therefore check if it times out instead of being signaled.
- `sem_timedwait()` will return 0 if it is signaled by `sem_post()`

So I understand the if-statement, however I don't understand the while loop. So it will loop while `sem_timedwait()` returns an error(?) AND while it is being signaled by a `sem_post()` call? (I clearly don't get the definition of `"EINTR The call was interrupted by a signal handler"`)

Example from man:

```
while ((s = sem_timedwait(&sem, &ts)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
    continue;       /* Restart if interrupted by handler */

/* Check what happened */

if (s == -1) {
    if (errno == ETIMEDOUT)
        printf("sem_timedwait() timed out\n");
    else
        perror("sem_timedwait");
} else
    printf("sem_timedwait() succeeded\n");
```

I thought it would work similar to this:

```
s = sem_timedwait(&sem, &ts)
if (errno == ETIMEDOUT) {
    // timed out after specified ts
}
else if (s == -1) {
    // error occurred
}
else {
    // interrupted by `sem_post()`, do something relying on shared resource
}
```

Comment: How much do you know about [*signals*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)? Perhaps reading little more about them should give you more information.

Comment: As for the loop, it will iterate as long as `sem_timedwait` returns with an error and the error is `EINTR`.

Comment: Note also that you should always check whether the return value of `sem_timedwait` is `-1` *before* checking `errno`. `errno` is only relevant iff `sem_timedwait` returned `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop :

```
while ((s = sem_timedwait(&sem, &ts)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
    continue;       /* Restart if interrupted by handler */
```

will loop until either the `sem_timedwait` call succeeds (ie. the `sem_post()` happens), or an error other than `EINTR` happens.

The [`EINTR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474299/checking-if-errno-eintr-what-does-it-mean) error is handled specially, because the [`sem_timedwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_timedwait.html) call can be interrupted at any time by a signal. This is not treated as an error, but as an interruption (which is what it *is*), and the call is just retried in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Any process can receive [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) . If that process is doing a system call that blocks the process when the signal is received, the system call will fail, and the global [errno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h) will be set to the special value `EINTR`. That way the process gets woken up again and can take action when a signal was received.

This is not a hard fail, it is mostly just information that a signal was received and one can safely do the same call again.

The code here is just following good practice and handling such a potential situation. As the code here doesn't really care that a signal was received, it just re-tries acquiring the semaphore.

Note, while most system calls can fail in this manner, most system calls are automatically re-started. i.e. your own code never sees that the call failed with EINTR, the system re-tries the system call again. This behavior can also be controlled when a signal handler is installed by when calling `sigaction()`.

`sem-timedwait()` however, is not a call that the system automatically re-starts, so your code have to deal with it.