# Why would std::process::Command::ouput fail?

Tags: error-handling, rust

What would cause `std::process:Command::output` to fail? If the callee program fails, the error will be captured as part of the resulting `Output.stderr`, so I guess `output` will only return an `Error` if the OS fails to create a new process for some reason? Is that something that I can safely ignore for my simple CLI tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There could be some issue opening the binary being executed (i.e. access denied, doesn't exist)
- When waiting for the process to finish, the `waitpid` syscall could be [interrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474299/checking-if-errno-eintr-what-does-it-mean)
- Getting the output involves creating a pipe, which will fail if the file descriptor limit is hit (`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` to check)
- It also involves opening a file, which will fail if the limit on open files is reached (`ulimit -n` to check)

You probably only need to worry about the first two: you can't do anything about hitting limits in the kernel.